# dojo EnchancedGrid items do not select programmatically in invisible part of the view

Tags: dojo, selection

The following code has to select items (indirect selection) programmatically, but this only happen in visible part of the table (or first 15 rows). Scrolled items remain unselected.

Is it possible to fix this?

```
var grid = context._events._gridView;
grid.selection.deselectAll();
var data = jsResponse.message.items;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {

    grid.store.fetch({
        query: {id: data[i].id},
        onComplete: function (items)
        {
            dojo.forEach(items, function (item, index)
            {
                console.debug(item.id + "/" +  index);
                try {
                    //grid.selection.addToSelection(item);
                    var idx = grid.getItemIndex(item);
                    grid.selection.setSelected(idx,true);
                }
                catch (e) {
                    console.debug(e);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: grid.store.fetch indeed calls onComplete for every required row, but then grid.selection.setSelected(idx,true) or grid.selection.addToSelection(item) set selection sucsessfully only on vsisble rows.

Answer (score 0):

Using rowsPerPage, and set it to huge value, helps to work around this bug.

```
gridView = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
        rowSelector: "20px",
        rowsPerPage: plugins.indirectSelection?1500:15,
        plugins: plugins
    },
    document.createElement('div'));
```